# Restrictions on symbol name in Emacs lisp

Tags: emacs, elisp, standards

To make myself clean, in C, identifier must match `[0-9_a-zA-Z]+` and it is bad practice, if it match `__.*` or `_[A-Z]+`. It can be read in standard. I want to know exactly the same about elisp. I know by experience, that I can use `:-@`, but not `#`. Please, point me to right place to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no hard limits, although a symbol with a name which cannot be easily accessed is of little practical use.

http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Creating-Symbols.html

Comment: Of course, I read this. But I am intrested in that, I cant't do `(setq #foo 2)`. Why? And what else cant I use in such simple way? I also know about `;`.

Comment: Those are restrictions of the Lisp reader, not restrictions on allowed symbol names. You cannot use an unquoted semicolon because it's masked by the comment syntax, but you can use indirections like `(soft-intern ";")` to create a symbol with that name. If your question is really "what are the restrictions of the Lisp reader" then your stated question, and my answer, are off the mark.

Comment: #number is used for number notation; parentheses, quotes, and question marks (for character constants like `?a`) also come to mind, and square brackets for vector notation ... I'm sure I'm probably missing a few still.